# Is there a space of all finite models?

Tags: general-topology, logic, model-theory

Let $\mathcal{L}=\{R_i\}_{i \in I}$ be a relational language. There is a natural construction of a compact space of countable $\mathcal{L}$-structures, namely, the space $$ \prod_{R_i \in \mathcal{L}} 2^{\mathbb{N}^{n_i}}$$
where $n_i$ is the arity of the relation symbol $R_i$.

Here the intuition behind the topology is that the more the relations of two structures agree on finite fragments of the underlying set (which is chosen as $\mathbb{N}$ without loss of generality) the closer these structures are. This idea will clearly break down if one considers finite $\mathcal{L}$-structures since a finite amount of data regarding its relations will enable us to distinguish a structure from all the others, so we should end up getting the discrete topology. Indeed, we do get this if $\mathcal{L}$ is finite and we replace $\mathbb{N}$ by $\{0,1,\dots,n\}$ and take the disjoint union of these spaces as $n$ ranges over $\mathbb{N}$.

Can one construct a topological space of all finite $\mathcal{L}$-structures other than the discrete space? Just to avoid any non-trivial topologies arising from the cardinality of $\mathcal{L}$, let us assume that $\mathcal{L}$ is finite; so we are looking for a countably infinite (preferably Hausdorff) topological space.

Obviously I'd prefer to have some kind of intuition behind the notion of closeness in this space. Given how much the space of countable structures has been studied, surely someone must have tried to construct such a space.

Comment: Given that there are only finitely many structures of bounded size, if you want the topology to be Hausdorff (or even $T_1$), then the only nontrivial "limits" will have to be as the size of structures goes to $\infty$.  So somehow you would need to be saying that a sequence of larger and larger structures "approaches" a finite structure that is smaller than all of them.  I don't see any reasonable way you could want that to happen.

Comment: @EricWofsey: Yes, if there is to be such a topology, because of your observation, we should first place structures of cardinality 1 in our space, then put the structures of cardinality 2 "around" these in a reasonable way and then put the structures of cardinality 3 around these ones etc. I was actually trying to come up with a metric where each structure is the limit of point of all its superstructures but have failed so far.

Comment: Topologically you get just a countable discrete space, that's true, but the topology is not the interesting part in the countable structures case either, you always get just a Cantor set.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to think of a way to topologize the set of finite $\mathcal{L}$-structures that resembles the idea behind the topology of the space of countable structures, namely, declaring the set of finite structures that have a common finite substructure as a basic open set. However, it produces a bad space in terms of separation axioms and whether or not this can become useful is another issue...

For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, let $\text{Mod}_n(\mathcal{L})$ denote the set of $\mathcal{L}$-structures with universe $\{0,1,\dots,n\}$ and set $\text{Mod}_{<\omega}(\mathcal{L})=\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \text{Mod}_n(\mathcal{L})$. For every $\mathcal{M} \in \text{Mod}_{<\omega}(\mathcal{L})$ set $$U_{\mathcal{M}}=\{\mathcal{N} \in \text{Mod}_{<\omega}(\mathcal{L}):  \mathcal{M} \text{ is a substructure of } \mathcal{N}\}$$
Here, when I say "is a substructure of", I do not mean "contains a copy of" but I actually do want $\mathcal{M}$ to be physically contained in $\mathcal{N}$ as a substructure with its interpretations as the restrictions of those of $\mathcal{N}$.

Given $\mathcal{M}$ and $\mathcal{M}'$ in $\text{Mod}_{<\omega}(\mathcal{L})$ with domains $\{0,1,\dots,n\}$ and $\{0,1,\dots,n'\}$ respectively, if we have $\mathcal{N} \in U_{\mathcal{M}} \cap U_{\mathcal{M}'}$, then the substructure of $\mathcal{N}$ generated by $\{0,1,\dots,n\}$ is $\mathcal{M}$ and the substructure of $\mathcal{N}$ generated by $\{0,1,\dots,n'\}$ is $\mathcal{M}'$. It follows that if $U_{\mathcal{M}} \cap U_{\mathcal{M}'} \neq \emptyset$, then we have $U_{\mathcal{M}} \subseteq U_{\mathcal{M}'}$ or $U_{\mathcal{M}'} \subseteq U_{\mathcal{M}}$ depending on whether $n' \leq n$ or $n \leq n'$.

It follows that the set $\{U_{\mathcal{M}}: \mathcal{M} \in \text{Mod}_{<\omega}(\mathcal{L})\}$ is a basis for a topology. Let us endow $\text{Mod}_{<\omega}(\mathcal{L})$ with the topology generated by this basis. Then $\text{Mod}_{<\omega}(\mathcal{L})$ is a $T_0$-space since if $\mathcal{A} \neq \mathcal{B}$ and $|A| \leq |B|$, then $\mathcal{A} \notin U_{\mathcal{B}}$ and $\mathcal{B} \in U_{\mathcal{B}}$. This space is not $T_1$ since if $\mathcal{A}$ is a substructure of $\mathcal{B}$, then every open set containing $\mathcal{A}$ also contains $\mathcal{B}$.

As Eric Wofsey mentioned in the comments, convergence in this space is a bit unusual. If there is a sequence of finite $\mathcal{L}$-structures, then any finite $\mathcal{L}$-structure which is eventually a substructure of the elements of the sequence is a limit of this sequence. This is simply because every point $\mathcal{M}$ has a smallest open neighborhood, namely, $U_\mathcal{M}$.

The subspaces $\text{Mod}_n(\mathcal{L})$ are discrete since $U_{\mathcal{M}} \cap \text{Mod}_n(\mathcal{L})= \{\mathcal{M}\}$ whenever $\mathcal{M} \in \text{Mod}_n(\mathcal{L})$. But instead of taking the disjoint union of these discrete spaces which would result in a discrete space, we are "gluing" them at each finite structure in a way that I honestly don't understand.

Comment: Re: the last paragraph, I think the right way to think about what's going on here is that we're topologizing a basis for another topological space: namely, points in this new space are basic opens in a more standard topology on the set of structures with domain $\omega$. This explains the bad separation properties, and the "gluing weirdness:" our points here are really open sets elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, but rather an addendum to your answer that is far too long for comments. To try to start getting a sense of your topology, I looked at three simple cases.

If $\mathscr{L}$ is empty, you’re just getting $\omega$ with the topology whose non-empty sets are the tails; call this space $W$.

If $\mathscr{L}$ has a single constant symbol, we can identity $\operatorname{Mod}_{<\omega}(\mathscr{L})$ with

$$\{\langle n,m\rangle\in\omega\times\omega:m\le n\}\,:$$

$\langle n,m\rangle$ corresponds to the model $\mathscr{M}(n,m)$ on $\{0,\ldots,n\}$ with the constant interpreted as $m$. $U_{\mathscr{M}(n,m)}=\{\mathscr{M}(k,m):k\ge n\}$, so $\operatorname{Mod}_{<\omega}(\mathscr{L})$ is homeomorphic to $W\times\omega$, where $\omega$ has the discrete topology.

If $\mathscr{L}$ has a single unary relation symbol $R$, $\operatorname{Mod}_n(\mathscr{L})$ is a discrete set of power $2^{n+1}$. For each $s:\{0,\ldots,n\}\to\{0,1\}$ let $\mathscr{M}_s\in\operatorname{Mod}_n(\mathscr{L})$ be the model for which $s$ is the indicator function of the interpretation of $R$. If $m,n\in\omega$, $m\le n$, $\mathscr{M}_s\in\operatorname{Mod}_m(\mathscr{L})$, and $\mathscr{M}_t\in\operatorname{Mod}_n(\mathscr{L})$, then $\mathscr{M}_t\in U_{\mathscr{M}_s}$ if and only if $s=t\upharpoonright\{0,\ldots,n\}$.

Let $T=\bigcup_{n\in\omega}{^n}2$, so that $\langle T,\subseteq\rangle$ is the full binary tree of height $\omega$, and for $t\in T$ let $U_t=\{s\in T:t\subseteq s\}$; $\{U_t:t\in T\}$ is a base for a topology $\tau$ on $T$. The previous paragraph shows that in this case $\operatorname{Mod}_{<\omega}(\mathscr{L})$ is homeomorphic to $2\times T$, where $2$ has the discrete topology. It would be homeomorphic to $T$ itself if you included the empty model.

Comment: Thanks for the comment/answer. I thought I had made up some weird meaningless space but your answer now made me curious about whether this space can be described nicely in terms of basic building blocks, such as your $W$ and $T$. I will try to look into more cases later.

Comment: @Burak: You’re welcome; it was fun. I suspect that it’s not bad as long as the language contains only constants and unary relations; after that it may get pretty messy.